# Xamarin UWP + Android ContentPage Navigation PushAsync

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, uwp, navigation

I'm converting an UWP application to Xamarin in the aim to use it on both Android and Windows devices.
I never used Xamarin before and I assume i'm doing a beginer mistake.

On my MainPage everything is OK :

[image: MainPage]

But when I'm clicking on the "Options" Button it didn't load a new page exept a grey banner in the upper part of the window :
[image: OptionsView]

To navigate from one page to another I followed this explanation : [Microsoft doc navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)

There's my code to change page in the MainPage.xaml.cs :

```
async void ButtonOptions_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            button_options.Source = "Assets/Option_Icon_1.png";
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
            var OptionsView = new OptionsView();
            await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() => Navigation.PushAsync(OptionsView, true));
            //this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(StorageView1));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { InterpretException("MainPage.ButtonStorage_Click()", ex); }
    }
```

And my OptionsView.xaml :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Stock_Manager_Xamarin.OptionsView"
         Title="Second Page">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Name:" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        </StackLayout>
            
        <Button x:Name="navigateButton" Text="Previous Page"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I tried different version of the xaml code without any change and I can't find a working sample.
Could someone can explain me where I'm doing a mistake ?

Comment: why are you doing `Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());` if `MainPage` is already what's currently displayed?

Comment: I've read it in another topic... but it was clearly a mistake. ColeX - MSFT gives the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrap current page inside navigation stack in `App.cs`, and set it as `MainPage`, so that we can do the navigation operation .

   ```
   public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
   ```
2. As `Jason` mentioned , it is no need to set `MainPage` again , just navigate directly , modify your code as below .

   ```
   void ButtonOptions_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
   {
       try
       {
           button_options.Source = "Assets/Option_Icon_1.png";
           var OptionsView = new OptionsView();
           Navigation.PushAsync(OptionsView, true);
       }
       catch (Exception ex) { InterpretException("MainPage.ButtonStorage_Click()", ex); }
   }
   ```